# Zsh glob: objects recursivley under sudirectories, excluding current/base directory

Tags: zsh, glob

I am trying to do a file name generation of all objects (files, directories, and so on) recursively under all subdirectories of the current directory. Excluding the objects in said current directory.

In other words, given:

```
--dir1 --dir2.1
|      | dir2.2 --file3.1
|      --file2.1
--file1
```

I want to generate:

```
./dir2.1
./dir2.2
./dir2.2/file3.1
./file2.1
```

I have set the EXTENDED_GLOB option, and I assumed that the following pattern would do the trick:

```
./**/*~./*
```

But it returns:

```
zsh: no matches found: ./**/*~./*
```

I don't know what the problem is, it should work.

./**/* gives:

```
./dir1
./dir2.1
./dir2.2
./dir2.2/file3.1
./file2.1
./file1
```

And ./* gives:

```
./dir1
./file1
```

How come ./**/*~./* fails? And more important, how can I generate the name of the elements recursively in the subdirectories excluding the elements in current/base directory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (1)`x~y` glob operator uses `y` as a shell's ordinally pattern matching rather than a file name generation, so `./**/*~./*` gives "no matches found":

```
% print -l ./**/*~./*
;# ./dir1   # <= './*' matches, so exclude this entry
;# ./dir2.1 # <= './*' matches, so exclude this entry
;# .. # ditto...
;# => finally, no matches found
```

The exclusion pattern `./*` matches everything generated by the glob `./**/*`, so zsh finally yields "no matches found". (zsh does not do filename generations for the `~y` part.)

We could make the exclusion pattern a little more precise/complicated form for excluding the elements in current directory. Such that it starts with `./` and has one or more characters other than `/`.

```
% print -l ./**/*~./[^/]## ;# use '~./[^/]##' rather than '~./*'
./dir1/dir2.1
./dir1/dir2.2
./dir1/dir2.2/file3.1
./dir1/file2.1
```

Then, to strip the current-dir-component `/dir1`, we could use the (2)`e`*string* glob qualifier, such that it removes the first occurrence of `/[^/]##` (for example `/dir1`):

```
# $p for avoiding repetitive use of the exclusion pattern.
% p='./[^/]##'; print -l ./**/*~${~p}(e:'REPLY=${REPLY/${~p[2,-1]}}':)
./dir2.1
./dir2.2
./dir2.2/file3.1
./file2.1
```

Or to strip it using ordinally array/replace rather than `e`*string* glob qualifier:

```
% p='./[^/]##'; a=(./**/*~${~p}) ; a=(${a/${~p[2,-1]}}); print -l $a
./dir2.1
./dir2.2
./dir2.2/file3.1
./file2.1
```

At last, iterating over current dir's dirs could do the job, too:

```
a=(); dir=;
for dir in *(/); do
  pushd "$dir"
  a+=(./**/*)
  popd
done
print -l $a
#=> ./dir2.1
    ./dir2.2
    ./dir2.2/file3.1
    ./file2.1
```

---

Here are some zsh documents.

(1)`x~y` glob operator:

> `x~y`
>
> (Requires `EXTENDED_GLOB` to be set.) Match anything that matches the pattern *x* but does not match *y*. This has lower precedence than any operator except `‘|’`, so `‘*/*~foo/bar’` will search for all files in all directories in `‘.’` and then exclude `‘foo/bar’` if there was such a match. Multiple patterns can be excluded by `‘foo~bar~baz’`. In the exclusion pattern (*y*), `‘/’` and `‘.’` are not treated specially the way they usually are in globbing.
>
> --- [zshexpn(1), `x~y`, Glob Operators](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators)

(2)`e`*string* glob qualifier:

> `e`*string*
>   `+`*cmd*
>
> ...
>   During the execution of string the filename currently being tested is available in the parameter `REPLY`; the parameter may be altered to a string to be inserted into the list instead of the original filename.
>
> --- [zshexpn(1), `e`*string*, Glob Qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers)

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly the solution I was looking for.